# ftp login using c#

Tags: c#, ftp

How do you Login to FTP using C#?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very nice FTP Client for C#

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ftplibrary.aspx

### Snippett from Link

```
//Get the basic FtpWebRequest object with the
//common settings and security
private FtpWebRequest GetRequest(string URI)
{
    //create request
    FtpWebRequest result = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(URI);
    //Set the login details
    result.Credentials = GetCredentials();
    //Do not keep alive (stateless mode)
    result.KeepAlive = false;
    return result;
}

/// <summary>
/// Get the credentials from username/password
/// </summary>
private System.Net.ICredentials GetCredentials()
{
    return new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
}
```

Comment: I tried this, had problems using it to FTP to a mainframe. Resorted to using the edtFTPnet component instead which worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Native FTP support in .NET is fiddly.

I suggest using the free edtFTPnet component - I have used this in enterprisey applications with no problems whatsoever.

http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnet/overview.html

Comment: Can you give some examples about why native support is fiddly?

Answer (score 3):

```
var url = "ftp://server";    
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
var ftp = System.Net.FtpWebRequest(some url);
ftp.Credentials = something;
```

I think... :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm just throwing my hat in the ring for anyone searching this topic.  Here is how I did this recently.  I made an FTPProvider class to handle the connection wiring and an FTPSettings class to keep everything modular.  This first line below makes the connection and returns the FtpWebRequest you will need to do things like download, delete, and get lists from the FTP server.  A complete list and examples can be found [here on the msdn.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx)

```
FtpWebRequest request = FTPProvider.GetFTPRequest(FTPProvider.Settings.FTPPath);

public class FTPProvider
{
    public FTPSettings Settings { get; set; }

    public FtpWebRequest ConnectToFtp(Uri ftpServerUri)
    {
        var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateDefault(ftpServerUri);
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Settings.User, Settings.Password);
        return request;
    }

    public FtpWebRequest GetFTPRequest(string filepath)
    {
        var ftpServerUri = new Uri(filepath);
        return ConnectToFtp(ftpServerUri);
    }


}
public class FTPSettings
{
    public string FTPPath;

    public string User;

    public string Password;
}
```