# How to get file from the folder using system.net.ftpclient

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to get file from "ftp://appupdate:website:21000/Sync" how can I get all file from folder Sync using System.Net.Ftpclient?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ftp login using c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541712/ftp-login-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Do a search : there is a lot of questions about FTP in C#, with free libraries or even native support !

Comment: I use system.net.ftpclient not ftpwebrequest

Comment: Same answer : do a search, tell us what you tried, and why it did'nt work. Your current question is too broad and we won't write code for you.